# ¿Por qué mi código en c me da fallo de segmentación?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente código en C

```
#include <strings.h>

char* are_you_playing_banjo(const char* name) {
  return tolower(name[0]) == 'r' ? malloc(strcat(name," plays banjo")) : malloc(strcat(name, " does not play banjo")) ;
}
```

pero el correr las pruebas unitarias me da el error:

```
Test Crashed
Exit code: 0
Signal code: 11
```

Este es el código de la prueba unitaria:

```
#include <criterion/criterion.h>

char* are_you_playing_banjo(const char*);

void do_test(char* testCase, char* expected) {
  char* actual = are_you_playing_banjo(testCase);
  cr_assert_str_eq(actual, expected);

  free(actual);
}

Test(sample_tests, should_pass_all_the_tests_provided) {
  do_test("Martin", "Martin does not play banjo");
  do_test("Rikke", "Rikke plays banjo");
}
```

¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Comment: @Trauma ¿Por qué quitar el compilador y la versión del lenuguaje que uso de las etiquetas?

Comment: Porque no tienen nada que ver con tu problema. Las funciones que usas son parte del estandar desde la versión C99, y están disponibles en cualquier compilador. En todo caso, sería C99, pero vamos, veo difícil encontrar compiladores que ni siquiera soporten esa versión. Tiene 19, casi 20 años ya :-)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87623/por-que-mi-codigo-en-c-me-da-fallo-de-segmentacion

Comment: No me deja ver la *kata*, no tengo cuenta. Piensa que mi respuesta posiblemente no sea la mas corta ni la mas optima, seguro que se puede mejorar. He intentado que sea fácil de entender solamente :-)

Comment: Y lo es, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un par de problemas:

- `strcat( )`, ciertamente, se usa para *concatenar* cadenas, es decir, añade una a la otra, pero ... **no** se encarga de gestionar la memoria; eso es cosa nuestra.
- `strcat( )` devuelve **un puntero**, no un tamaño necesario.
- `malloc( )` espera un tamaño, y tu le estás pasando un puntero.

Una posible solución a tu problema es:

```
char* are_you_playing_banjo( const char* name ) {
  const char *toAppend[] = {
    " plays banjo",
    " does not play banjo"
  };
  int index = ( tolower( name[0] ) == 'r' ) ? 0 : 1;
  char *result = malloc( strlen( name ) + strlen( toAppend[index] ) + 1 );

  *result = 0; // Para que strcat( ) añada al principio.
  strcat( result, name ); // Añadimos 'name'.
  strcat( result, toAppend[index] ); // Añadimos el 'estado'.

  return result;
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué `*result = 0` ?

Comment: Porque `strcat( )` añade al final de la cadena, que está marcado con un `0`. Y como llamamos a `malloc( )`, esto nos devuelve un bloque de memoria con valores aleatorios. Ponemos el primer byte a `0` para que `strcat( )` sepa en que lugar añadir; en este caso, en el primer byte.

Comment: Se puede evitar usando `calloc( )`, que nos rellena el bloque de memoria con valores `0`, pero ... es menos eficiente :-)

Comment: y por que el ternario en vez de simplemente `int condition = tolower( name[0] ) == 'r'`?

Comment: Para que se vea mas claro. Se puede poner tal y como dices, sin ningún problema. `==` devuelve `1` si la condición es cierta, pero me pareció mas fácil de entender así.

Comment: Piensa que no se cual es tu nivel de conocimientos del lenguaje, ni el nivel de otros posibles usuarios que visiten esta pregunta :-)